# Evaluate integral using Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral $\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ with $\vec{F}$ and $C$ as given and the direction integration along $C$ being clockwise as seen by a person standing at the origin. $\vec{F}=[-z, 5x, -y]$ and $C$ is the ellipse $x^2+y^2=4, z=x+2$.

The problem wants us to use Stokes' theorem, which says $$ \int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int\int \text{curl} \ \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} $$

I know exactly what I have to do, but I'm having trouble coming up with the unit normal vector to evaluate this surface integral. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which do you want to evaluate, left side or right side or both?

Comment: The question is asking to calculate the line integral without actually calculating the line integral (ie. apply Stokes' Theorem and calculate the surface integral instead)

Comment: then calculate the right side.

Comment: Like I explain in the post, I'm not sure how you come up with $d\vec{S}=\hat{n}dS$.

Answer (score 1):

The [curl is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curl+%5B-z%2C+5x%2C+-y%5D) the curl is $(-1,-1,5)$. The surface of that vertical plane inclined along x-axis in between that cylinder is an ellipse like this.
[image]

The [parametric equation of this ellipse](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7B2+r+Cos%5B%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D+%2C+2++r++Sin%5B%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D+%2C++++2+r++Cos%5B%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D+%2B+2+%7D%2C+%7B%5C%5BTheta%5D%2C+0%2C+2+Pi%7D%2C+%7Br%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D) is  given by 
$$\Phi( r, \theta ) = ( 2 r \cos(\theta), 2 r\sin(\theta), 2 r \cos(\theta)+2)$$

To calculate [surface integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields), (possibly $-$ve since you are going clockwise loop)
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi } (-1,-1,5) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \Phi}{ \partial r} \times \frac{\partial \Phi}{ \partial \theta} \right ) d\theta d\phi = 24 \pi $$

**Another way** to calculate it, note that ellipse lies in surface $S \implies z - x = 2 $ bound below by circle at $(0,0)$ of unit length.
You can use another formula.
$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2} } (-1, -1, 5) \cdot \vec \nabla S dy dx = 4 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} (-1, -1, 5) \cdot (-1, 0 , 1) dy dx = 24 \pi   $$

Comment: Doesn't $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}$ have to be a unit normal vector?

Comment: @Lefty yes that thing has to be unit vector, but again you are evaluating on the surface ... so it get's multiplied again by $|\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}|$.

note that 
$$ \iint |\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}| dr d\theta $$ should give you area of that ellipse.